# how to perform manipulations on categories on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of different time series of different experiments. each participant made several Trials of an experiment.

the data contains columns of some features. and I want to perform some analysis on some feature columns and update the data frame accordingly.

For example, I want to add column as mean of feature 1 of each trial and a column as shifted feature 1 of each trial.

this is what I have:

| participant ID | Trial | Feature 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 |

This is what I want to get:

| participant ID | Trial | Feature 1 | mean of feature 1 | feature 1 shifted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | na |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | na |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 5 | na |
| 2 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | na |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 2 |

Comment: could you explain more how is the column "feature 1 shifted" generated?

Comment: sure: df['column'].shift()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `groupby()`,`transform()` and `shift()`:

```
df['mean of feature 1']=df.groupby(['participant ID','Trial'])['Feature 1'].transform('mean')
df['feature 1 shifted']=df.groupby(['mean of feature 1'])['Feature 1'].shift()
```

output of `df`:

```
   participant ID   Trial   Feature 1   mean of feature 1   feature 1 shifted
0       1               1           2           3               NaN
1       1               1           4           3               2.0
2       1               2           1           2               NaN
3       1               2           3           2               1.0
4       2               1           4           5               NaN
5       2               1           6           5               4.0
6       2               2           2           4               NaN
7       2               2           6           4               2.0
```